# SMS шлюз для верификации номера телефона

Tags: php, json

Есть форма отправки с полями имени фамилией email и телефона.
Нужно реализовать проверку номера телефона с помощью смс кода.
Возможно ли это реализовать бесплатно, если нет то какие есть для этого сервисы?

Comment: Вам нужен любой смс шлюз (коих огромное количество), поддерживающий адекватное API. Рекомендации по конкретным шлюзам можно расчесть за рекламу, поэтому гугл в помощь. Бесплатно - есть подобный опыт: https://habr.com/ru/post/111305/ Но там тоже не бесплатно...

Comment: Если бы это было бесплатно, спамеры властвовали бы хлеще чем сейчас

Comment: Отвечал тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/983621/338100 Сам использую этот сервис. Советую.